# How to handle Error: socket hang up while waiting Node and React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sockets, http-status-codes

[image]I've been working on a NodeJS express route the accepts a get request, counts and analyzes about 15000+ data, so from my react app (Axios) when I hit the get URL, the processing and analyzing takes more than 4 to 5 min and the socket hangs up on about 2min what should I do to make my react app wait longer or get a response in any other way. Maybe an HTTP 202 has its way but I don't know how to do it, Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the wise choice is to use [websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket) or [socket-io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io) for such use cases.

but you can also :

use express timeout . to keep the connection alive between the client and the server:
first, install :

```
npm install connect-timeout
```

after that change your server entry point(app.js) file.

```
var express = require('express')
var timeout = require('connect-timeout')

// example of using this top-level; note the use of haltOnTimedout
// after every middleware; it will stop the request flow on a timeout
var app = express()
app.use(timeout('400s'))

app.use(haltOnTimedout)


// Add your routes here, etc.

function haltOnTimedout (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.timedout) next()
}

app.listen(3000)
```

for more details : [express official](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/timeout.html)

or if you don't want to install any third-party module :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
   res.setTimeout(120000, function(){
      console.log('Request has timed out.');
         res.send(408);
      });

      next();
 });
```